# remote jobs as standard user

Tags: powershell, remoting, credentials

OK, I'm on a Sunday roll! With a newly stubbed toe. I am trying to do some remoting, and specifically I want to run the remote job as the logged in user. Who is not a local admin. If I run as an admin user it works, even if the standard user is logged in. But if I run with the standard user credentials it fails with Access Denied. Make that user a local admin and it works. I am nearly certain the issue is simply that you can't run a remote job in the context of a non admin user, but I can't seem to find any documentation of that. So, can someone verify this is the case and I will start looking at alternatives? Or clue me in on the secret sauce required to do it with a standard user. ;)

Also, for context, the goal here is to automate some user cleanup for a conference lab environment. Every machine in the lab has the same user account. I want a script on the server that I can run, that runs a remote job as the standard user, and does a number of things, including clearing the user desktop, my documents and favorites, and wiping out all shortcuts in the task bar and rebuilding with the conference standard. The idea is to run this manually just before the beginning of each session, so the delegates in each session get that nice "new computer" smell. I already have it working as a logon type arrangement, but I don't like that because sometimes a machine needs to be rebooted mid session and I don't want to wipe things out prematurely. I can also do it as a scheduled task on each machine, but then there is the issue of a session running long. I don't want to have the scheduled tasks run to soon. I really want this to be initiated manually, when the time is right.

The alternative approach I am looking at is making these tasks test for a particular env var or reg key, which I could push via a script and then reboot. The tasks would then run, but a reboot later wouldn't run these tasks because the flag to trigger the task would be missing. The issues there are, I need to enable remote registry, which I don't like, and I would need to give all users right to the flag key in HKLM. Or I could do it with a system env var, but then I need to have a second script remove the flag, since a standard user can't modify a system env var. All of which is a LOT more compacted than just running a job as the delegate user. :(

And, as an added issue, I had hoped to have the remote job fire a balloon notification letting anyone at the machine know what was happening. But it seems I lose that ability too, so I wonder if anyone has a good approach to sending a message to a remote machine, ideally something that works in Win 7 and Win 8/10 and maybe even allows a temporary message at the logon screen (but that is a bit of a tangent).

Current attempt looks like this

```
Invoke-Command -sessionOption:(New-PSSessionOption -noMachineProfile) -computerName:$machine -argumentList: $filePath –scriptblock {
   param (
      [String]$filePath
   )

      & powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file $filePath

   } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
```

EDIT: permission code

```
$sddl = (Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name "Microsoft.PowerShell").SecurityDescriptorSDDL
$sid = (New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users").Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value

$security_descriptor = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList @($false, $false, $sddl)
$security_descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess("Allow", $sid, 268435456, "None", "None")

# Convert the Security Descriptor back into SDDL
$security_descriptor.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All)
```

Comment: How about having scheduled task, which will run under user credentials, but trigger it manually by admin user?

Comment: Have you tried remote session without a profile? `Invoke-Command -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile) $servername -ScriptBlock $command -Cred $creds`

Comment: Jan, I tried adding -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile) to my otherwise working Invoke-Command, with no luck. I assume $servername in your example is related to -computerName?  In any case, my full Invoke-Command is added to the OP above.

Comment: Do you made any changes in PowerShell session configuration on remote computer to allow standard users to connect? By default only administrators and remote management users allowed to establish remote PowerShell session. `Get-PSSessionConfiguration|Format-List Name,SecurityDescriptorSddl,Permission`

Comment: Aha, now that's progress! Thanks PetSerAI. Now off to see if Set-PSSessionConfiguration can be used to permanently make that change. I just found a Hey, Scripting Guy! post that talks about it, but as usual for that blog a cut and paste results in code that doesn't work, so I'll need to try to figure out what he was trying to do.

Comment: Aaaand, stil no joy. I found a couple of resources, and ended up with the permissions code added up top. I did try to assign permissions to a group, which I have done with file and folder permissions before. And the code doesn't throw an error when assigning permissions, but I still get Access Denied when I try to run the remote job. Perplexed.

Comment: I just check on fresh installed Windows 8.1: `Set-WSManQuickConfig` plus `Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI` is enough to enable normal users to establish remote PowerShell session.

Comment: Hmm, must be something different with Win 7, or something else I am doing wrong, as that is not working on my end. But, I suspect it's because I need to actually manually do something with that SecurityDescriptorUI once it's shown? I assume there is a mechanism to automate whatever needs done, and user interaction is not the only mechanism?

Comment: And, after adding the specific user with full rights, I can now get the script to run, but the script itself then fails. I am just trying to write a file to the desktop to validate that things are working, and that is failing with Permission Denied, Unauthorized Access Exception. So, progress! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh! Sometimes I solve a problem after working on it for a while, and when things still don't fully work, I assume I haven't fully solved the problem. In this case, I actually have a totally new problem (for a new thread) and the remoting issue is solved. The revised code here is what I ended up with.

```
$sid = (New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount 'NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users').Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
$sddl = (Get-Item WsMan:\localhost\service\rootSDDL).Value 
$securityDescriptor = New-Object -typeName: Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor($false, $false, $sddl)
$securityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess('Allow', $sid, 268435456, 'None', 'None')

$newSddl = $securityDescriptor.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All)

Set-PSSessionConfiguration -name: 'Microsoft.PowerShell' -securityDescriptorSddl: $newSddl -force > $null
```